# Quanta LB4M Switch - missing VTP

Tags: networking, switch

I have a Quanta LB4M Gigabit switch and according to the user manual (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1035546/Quanta-Lb4m.html?page=330) it should support the VTP Protocol but when I connect to the switch console there is no trace of the VTP feature.
This feature as been removed with the recent firmware?

```
(Switching) #show version

Switch: 1

System Description............................. LB4M 48x1G 2x10G, 1.1.0.8, VxWorks 6.6
Machine Type................................... LB4M 48x1G 2x10G
Machine Model.................................. LB4M
Serial Number.................................. 
FRU Number.....................................
Part Number.................................... BCM56514
Maintenance Level.............................. A
Manufacturer................................... 0xbc00
Burned In MAC Address.......................... 00:26:
Software Version............................... 1.1.0.8
Operating System............................... VxWorks 6.6
Network Processing Device...................... BCM56514_A0


Additional Packages............................ FASTPATH QOS
```

Comment: What does "show vtp status" give you? If you don't have multiples of these switches I wouldn't worry about vtp not being in the firmware. Vtp just automates the vlan configuration process across many switches. I was under the impression vtp was Cisco proprietary.

Comment: Hi @Tim_Stewart "show vtp status" it returns that the command is not found/doesn't exist. Would be useful for me to have the VTP because I already use it with other five cisco switches. VTP as far I know it's Cisco proprietary, maybe Quanta have removed it in the latest firmwares due to some license violation I suppose

Answer (score 0):

The Vlan trunking protocol is a Cisco proprietary feature. (Exclusive to Cisco, and licenced third parties.)

Despite it's name, which can be confusing to networking new-comers it has nothing to do with "trunking".

But it does have everything to do with ease of administration for large switched networks, as it propigates vlan switching information from a server switch in the vtp domain. It allows you to save hours of work when configuring vlans in large networks, because you don't have to ssh into every switch to configure new vlans or remove them.

There is a caveat though, the switch with the highest configuration number will propigate it's information to all other switches in the vtp domain. So if you have configured a new switch in a lab, you need to reset it's config number back to zero. This is to insure that when you plug it into the production network it doesn't destroy the running vlan configurations across the whole network. it should be used with caution.

If you do not have multiples of switches, the benefits of vtp are negligible.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN_Trunking_Protocol